# Cannot sync with sitecore, error related to Access Guid

Tags: sitecore, tds

I've installed the sitecore connector. But when I try to sync, I get a "server not found, 500 error". The sitecore admin panel works fine in the browser.
When trying to use the Test button in the TDS project properties, I would get the following error:

[image]

I have checked the Access Guid in both the TDS project properties and the web.config of the _DEV folder in the deployed website in inetpub, they are identical.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: After this happens, go to Output window in Visual Studio and select TDS from the drop down. That will show you the error.

Comment: Do you have multiple TDS projects? If so make sure that the Access Guid is the same for all projects (or better, use a [Global Config](https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/globalconfig) for this setting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make TDS work in your local solution, you need to right click the TDS project, select Properties and make sure you have the "Install Sitecore Connector" checked under the Build tab. Click on TEST and let the process run.

If you have multiple TDS projects in the same solution, make sure you have the same GUID defined on each project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually it was something else, the TDS crashed for being too out of sync. When I tried syncing using a more up to date database, it had no problem syncing.

Comment: P.S. i think i know you, weren't you involved in some projects with Alex Dima, back in high-school?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I solved this by removing the _DEV folder on my website root which allowed TDS to install the connector again.

Answer (score 0):

In Build tab, please make sure you have correct setting for 
1. Sitecore Web URL - Sitecore URL
(http://example.com/sitecore)

2. Sitecore Deploy Folder - Path of the Website folder
   (for example: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website, where http://example.com is pointing)

In my case, Sitecore Deploy Folder was pointing to incorrect folder. After correction, it worked like charm.

Answer (score -1):

for all errors, this solution is helpful. Currently, we have the following code in web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="File"> 
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/> 
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/www/home/page-not-found" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/> 
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/> 
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" path="/error-500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/> 
</httpErrors>
```

We should replace it with this one:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File"> 
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/> 
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/www/home/page-not-found" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/> 
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/> 
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" path="/error-500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/> 
</httpErrors>
```

which we deleted from the above code this:  `existingResponse="Replace"`